# Git push results in "fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument" error

Tags: git, heroku

After sleuthing for about 3 hours now I managed to give myself a headache and not found a fix to this error:

```
Compressing objects: 100% (228/228), done.
Write failed: The connection was abortediB | 3 KiB/s
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:---------.git'
```

I am pushing a commit to heroku, and the above is thrown out. How do I fix this?

Comment: How large is the app?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson About 10MB

Comment: Ok, that would exclude size limit problems, had that message before when I pushed a too large app.

Comment: I just had a similar issue (same error) trying to push my app on a hotel connection. In this case there must have been an upload limit that caused the same error. I tried a different connection, and it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this happening on every deploy?  You will occasionally see network failures when pushing to Heroku's git remote.

I've always been able to work around this by re-pushing.  If Heroku thinks the latest commit has already been pushed, create a NOOP commit and force-deploy it:

```
touch foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -m 'NOOP'
git push heroku --force
```

...and if that works, you can remove the NOOP commit you made locally:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: This works, I was facing same issue and I try deleting one file which was not in use.  And it makes new commit.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Heroku just glitch for no reason. It just happened one hour ago. Now it is fixed.