# Git push not working but "git clone" and SSH does

Tags: windows, git, debian

I set up a Debian server that uses SSH for shell access and git repos.  I created a bare repo on it and using ssh was able to clone it to my Windows 8 workstation, however when trying to push changes back to the Debian server I get the error depicted here:

[image]

```
Read from remote host 174.52.5.192: Connection reset by peer
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: invalid argument
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@174.52.5.192:/home/git/repos/space-junk.git/'
```

I use this work station regularly for shell access to the same server via SSH so I know inability to access SSH isn't the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: is it consistent? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20315896/6309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the first push should be:

```
git push -u origin master
```

That will link the local branch master to its remote tracking one origin/master

Then, after that first push, you will be able (for all the subsequent push) to do a simple:

```
git push
```

See more at "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

I got it working!  It turns out the proper command was

```
git push origin master
```

The Windows version didn't have a descriptive enough error message but I got it working by switching over to Linux, which told me my command was wrong.